# Flutter: How to pass tapped text between pages?

Tags: flutter, ontap

I have created two pages
displays data from firestore

in one page it shows list of collections as text which is tapabble
(it is a subcollection)
need to display relevent subcollections in second page
please help

I have hard coded subcollection and displayed , but need to be dynamic please help

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below example code for passing arguments

```
class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SecondScreen(
                  dataList: ["Data"],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            "Second Screen",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List dataList;
  const SecondScreen({Key key, this.dataList}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          widget.dataList[0].toString(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```